# Swift Programming - How to set up app for taking turns

Tags: ios, swift, button

So I am attempting to code an application that would allow me and a friend to keep track of a dart game. In the game there are several different buttons that will allow the user to add or subtract one or two from the users score. I have the buttons and have created outlets but just ran into the question how do I tell the buttons which user they are supposed to to scoring. I have attached a picture of the basic UI and some of the code that I am using. Any advice would be really really appreciated. I just need to know how to tell the app which users turn it is, I was thinking would it be possible to add a button that would say "Next Turn" and you push the buttons to reflect the score of the player and then press "Next Turn" and it switches players. Therefore scoring would effect the next players turn. This makes sense to me on paper but I really dont know where to start to get that to function. Would you also mind taking a look at the code I have to make the labels reflect the score changes, and see if that logic makes sense?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var user1Score: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var user2Score: UILabel!

@IBAction func hit(sender: AnyObject) {

     user1Score.text = "+1"

}

@IBAction func miss(sender: AnyObject) {
}

@IBAction func doublePlus(sender: AnyObject) {
}

@IBAction func doubleMinus(sender: AnyObject) {
}

@IBAction func triplePlus(sender: AnyObject) {
}

@IBAction func tripleMinus(sender: AnyObject) {
}

@IBAction func penalty(sender: AnyObject) {
}
```

Here is the image of `mainStoryBoardUI`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a class property to keep track of the current player.  Store the scores in an array and use the `currentPlayer` as the index for which value to update.  Here is a very basic approach:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var currentName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var user1Score: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var user2Score: UILabel!

    var names = ["Fred", "Joe"]
    var currentPlayer = 0
    var scores = [0, 0]

    func updateUI() {
        currentName.text = names[currentPlayer]
        user1Score.text = "\(scores[0])"
        user2Score.text = "\(scores[1])"
    }

    @IBAction func changePlayers() {
        currentPlayer = 1 - currentPlayer
        updateUI()
    }

    @IBAction func hit() {
        scores[currentPlayer]++
        updateUI()    
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the thorough example , I was able to employ a strategy similar to the example that you provided which is working well. I have one question if I were to try and set up a new game button, and an undo last button how would I go about doing that?

Comment: New game, just set scores back to zero, current player to zero and call updateUI. For undo, you could add a class var to store a copy of scores before changing them. On undo button, set scores back to the saved value and call updateUI.

Comment: Awesome thank you so much! One last thing. When you get to 20 in this game, I want the userScore to display bullseye, because thats what you need to win. However in trying to do this I keep getting errors because I am trying to utilize the string "bullseye" for an int variable. Heres what I have maybe you could take a look.  @IBAction func newGame(sender: AnyObject) {
        newGame()
        let bulls : String = "\(scores)"
        if scores[currentPlayer] > 20 {
            bulls[currentPlayer] = "Bullseye to Win"
        } else {
            scores[currentPlayer] = scores[currentPlayer]  }

Comment: ^^That question is a bit more important, but also how would I tell the class to save a copy of the scores before changing them? Would it not just reference the initial values?

Comment: In updateUI, check if score is greater than 20 and set label to bullseye, otherwise set it to the score as shown above.

Comment: Just save scores to a class var called prevScores anytime before you change a score. Undo would just set scores to prevScores and call updateUI.

Comment: Vacawama would you mind giving me an example of how to make the label allow a string. I cant figure out how to let it say bullseye it keeps saying that I have it set as an integer. I have googled but none of the solutions seem to be working.